# Getting the .each loop result with the lowest number from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an API response from a shipping API that I would like to automatically choose the lowest shipping rate by default.

Here is the json:

```
[
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Letter", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>0.8, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Large Envelope or Flat", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>1.3, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.84, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>7.82, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Medium Flat Rate Box", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>12.8, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Small Flat Rate Box", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>7.5, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Large Flat Rate Box", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>17.6, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Flat Rate Envelope", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>6.95, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Flat Rate Padded Envelope", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>7.55, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Regional Rate Box A", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>9.95, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Regional Rate Box B", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>16.1, "otherCost"=>0.0},
  {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Legal Flat Rate Envelope", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>7.25, "otherCost"=>0.0}
]
```

I would then like to define the lowest priced one to then pass to the payment processor.

I tried using  `<%= rate["shipmentCost"].min %>` but got `undefined method`min' for 0.8:Float`... Which 0.8 is the lowest option, from the json response.

How can I have the each loop, or a loop in general, spot the lowest `rate["shipmentCost"], and then define that so I can use it to add to the price of the goods.

for instance, I would like to do something like:

`rate_to_use = rate["shipmentCost"].min`
and then use "price + rate_to_use = total" for processing the payment.  Then later for shipping a label will be created using the same lowest rate or match it.

Comment: Something along the lines of `cheapest_rate = rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }` ?

Comment: Wow you'er a beast.  I did: `@cheapest_rate = @rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }
    @cheapest_rate_number = @cheapest_rate["shipmentCost"]` to get the number alone but both rate will come in handy also to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#min_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by):

```rb
cheapest = @shipping_rates.min_by{|rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to add a little to this: if there's a chance a JSON hash contains a `nil` value or the key isn't found, @Vasfed's (very good) answer will raise an `ArgumentError`.

```
[1, nil].min_by(&:itself)
# => ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 1 failed
```

Therefore, I'd use:

```
@shipping_rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] || Float::INFINITY }
# or
@shipping_rates.compact.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }

# e.g.
[1, nil].min_by { |x| x || Float::INFINITY }
# => 1
[1, nil].compact.min_by(&:itself)
# => 1
```

That way you'll avoid any such errors.

There's one caveat with using `Float::INFINITY` here: if you don't have any `shipmentCost`s available, you'll be left rendering infinity. Therefore, you would want to wrap this in an equality check to avoid this:

```
<% cheapest = @shipping_rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] || Float::INFINITY }["shipmentCost"] %>
<%= cheapest unless cheapest == Float::INFINITY %>
```

That leaves me thinking the option with compact is the way to go :) Hope this helps:

```
<%= @shipping_rates.compact.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] %>
```

Comment: Did this help at all @uno?