# Getting lowest number/integer available from json response in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not really sure how to question this as a title...

but this is the situation and issue:

I take Order's from an API.  While taking the order in, I want to add a shipping rate based off the weight of the product.  I use an API from stamps to receive rates and I want to charge the least expensive rate available from the stamps API response.

Here is my attempt to get the rate (which works for displaying on front-end but not seeming to work in the following)....

```
...
rates = Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates({...})

cheapest_rate = rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }
cheapest_rate_number = cheapest_rate["shipmentCost"]
```

**error:**

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer) on line 75
```

line 75: `cheapest_rate = rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'] }`

The goal is to take the lowest number available, use that for `@order.shipping_rate` to then use for calculating the total payment for processing.

The `@rates` JSON response looks like this:

```
 [{"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.66, "otherCost"=>0.0}, {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>6.95, "otherCost"=>0.0}]
```

but with more than one option.

**How can I** take my current code and or new code to get the lowest integer from `\"shipmentCost\"`, define it and then pass it through to the model without the error from above

Comment: `rate['shipmentCost']` is a string, you need to convert it to a comparable entity, ex. an integer using `to_i`, in order to have `min_by` to compare the rates and find the cheapest one.

Assuming you're parsing the json with something like JSON.parse(...) could you please post the parsed JSON?

Comment: @microspino I tried `cheapest_rate = rates.min_by { |rate| rate['shipmentCost'].to_i }` but got the same error.

Comment: the `@rates` value is not a valid json string, could you please post the raw and parsed json?

Comment: I guess the end of @rates ```\"otherCost\"=>0.0}"``` makes that invalid json. Remove the ```}"``` at the end

Comment: @microspino I updated the json response.  I was mixing up 2 different scenarios.  The one i previously had up was from when i submijt a form when choosing a `@rates` from a radio_button in a form (not related to this a)

Comment: Please confirm that in rates you have parsed value coming from following `rates = Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates({...})`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The JSON you have provided above (and the missing definition for whatever `Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates` is?) does not give us sufficient information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add response of `Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates({...})`

Comment: @uno as far as i can tell the parsed JSON response you posted works fine: 

`[{"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.66, "otherCost"=>0.0}, {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>6.95, "otherCost"=>0.0}].min_by {|r| r['shipmentCost'] }`

results in: 

`{"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.66, "otherCost"=>0.0}`

Please post one that generates the error.

Comment: @uno also, saw your other related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752948/getting-the-each-loop-result-with-the-lowest-number-from-json
I'm not sure it's fair to have us answering every single step of your problem in different questions...

Comment: and also here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765464/saving-json-response-in-create

Comment: @uno - I am pretty much sure the response of the `Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates({...})` is not exactly this `[{"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.66, "otherCost"=>0.0}, {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>6.95, "otherCost"=>0.0}]`

Answer (score 0):

> [{"serviceName"=>"USPS First Class Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_first_class_mail", "shipmentCost"=>2.66, "otherCost"=>0.0}, {"serviceName"=>"USPS Priority Mail - Package", "serviceCode"=>"usps_priority_mail", "shipmentCost"=>6.95, "otherCost"=>0.0}]

From this array of hashes, you can simply do:

```
rates = Shipstation::Shipment.get_rates({...})

cheapest_rate_number = rates.collect { |h| h["shipmentCost"].to_f }.min
```

The eerror you posted suggests that not all `"shipmentCost"` values are integer or float, so we are just converting them to float to be safe even if some are integer/float and some are strings.